# Render the action that initiated update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I have a **SettingsController** with actions **account** and **profile**, and also an **update** that looks like:

```
  def update
    @player = current_user
    if @player.update_attributes(params[:player])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      @title = "Edit"
      render
    end
end
```

Now the profile and account actions each have a corresponding view, with a form to edit some records of the Player model.

When you try to save one of those forms, and it fails, ie. it didn't pass validation, it **should render the action that initialized the update** again, so it can display appropiate error messages.

But the problem is, how do I know which of both requested the update, and render the right one? Basically some sort of equivalent of redirect_to :back is what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is ugly but works :)

```
render Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)[:action]
```

Comment: ... I guess it's a compliment :)

Comment: You're right, this is ugly..! But if it works... Do you know if anything new has come up since 2011? Thanks!!!

Comment: It doesn't work cross-controllers. I have a dashboard `administration#dashboard` whose view is `administration/dashboard.html.erb` which lets admins update employees through `employees#update`, and using your method, I have a missing template error because the dashboard is in the subfolder `/administration/` and rails is only looking inside `/` and `/employees/`

Comment: Ah actually `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)` returns a hash of `:controller` and `:action`, so you can just join the two by `/` to solve the folder problem. `render Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer).map{ |k,v| v }.join('/')`

Comment: it still works in 2022! Not sure if there's a prettier way of doing it?

Answer (score -1):

Usually you can fix this by applying a pattern:

```
def edit
  @title = "Edit"

  # ...
end

def update
  # Update using the exception-generating variant
  @player.update_attributes!(params[:player])

  # ... More actions if successful

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  self.edit
  render(:action => 'edit')
end
```

This is often simplified by having a `before_filter` that handles the loading of the model instance for you.

Since this can be used a lot, sometimes you can wrap that into a delegation method:

```
def fallback_render(action)
  send(action)
  render(:action => action)
end
```