# how to update two different attributes on two different pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model with name and password attributes.  When the user clicks on 'Edit' I want just the name field to be editable and validated but not the password field.  And vice versa for when the user clicks on 'Reset Password'.
I think my main problem is how do I turn password validation off during the name field edit and how do I turn off name validation during the password edit?

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { class: "form_settings" } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <p><span><%= f.label :name %></span>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**reset_password.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { class: "form_settings" } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <p><span><%= label_tag :old_password, "Current Password" %></span>
    <%= password_field_tag :old_password %>
  </p>

  <p><span><%= f.label :password %></span>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>

  <p><span><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></span>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </p>

  <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if params[:old_password]
    if @user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
      @user.update_attributes(password: params[:user][:password])
      flash[:success] = "Password has been updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Current password is incorrect"
      render :reset_password
    end
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "User name updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

My other problem is that password and password_confirmation validation is not working.  This is what I have in the model:

```
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true
```

**UPDATE**
Got the password to reset and the validation working with this code:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if params[:old_password]
    if @user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
      if params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]
        @user.update_attributes(password: params[:user][:password])
        flash[:success] = "Password has been updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "Passwords don't match"
        render :reset_password
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Current password is incorrect"
      render :reset_password
    end
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "User name updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

But it seems too complicated for me.  Anyone see an easier solution?

But I still have the problem of editing the name field.  It's saying password can't be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix the name edit and the password reset on the same action.

Create one action that will update the attributes of your user, the `password` field should not be white listed with `attr_accessible`

Create one other action that will deal with the password reset.

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "User name updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def reset_password
  if params[:old_password] && @user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
    if params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]
      @user.password = params[:user][:password]
      flash[:success] = "Password has been updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Passwords don't match"
      render :reset_password
    end
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Current password is incorrect"
    render :reset_password
  end
end
```

This way, each action has its semantic role.

Btw, I hope you're using something like bcrypt to store the password.

Comment: For some reason the update action gets called when I try to reset the password like this.

Comment: Do you use a form ? You should point each button to a different action

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Did not know you can put an action into a form_for.  I'm finally at a point where I'm understanding fellow Rails programmers' answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move validation logic to model and keep the controller clean.

```
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, if: password?, on: :update
validates :name, presence: true, if: name?, on: :update
```

This is Required when u create the record. Just add `on: :create`

```
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, on: :create
validates :name, presence: true, on: :create
```

And modify your controller like this,

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.authenticate(params[:old_password]) if params[:old_password]
  return redirect_to @user, notice: "Sucessfully updated" if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  render Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)[:action]
end
```

Used render idea from this link:
[Render the action that initiated update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207846/render-the-action-that-initiated-update)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understnad what if: password? and if: name? do.  Are they methods I need to build?

Comment: Hmmm. They are rails methods, if password has some value it will return true otherwise false, same holds for name as well. When u update through reset password The First Validation will Run, When U update the name only at that case the second validaion will run.

Comment: I think it needs to be with a colon :password?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...but it looks kinda ugly:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if params[:old_password]
    if @user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
      if params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]
        @user.update_attributes(password: params[:user][:password])
        flash[:success] = "Password has been updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "Passwords don't match"
        render :reset_password
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Current password is incorrect"
      render :reset_password
    end
  elsif params[:user][:name].blank?
    flash[:error] = "Name can't be blank"
    render :edit
  else
    @user.update_attribute(:name, params[:user][:name])
    flash[:success] = "User name updated"
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```